# Display searches data on another page <div>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a search bar searching on `index.php` page. But i want to show the result on `coupons.php`. How to do it in AJAX.

**NOTE:**  `#search_result` is a div of coupons.php file where i want to display the result.

**AJAX**

```
$("document").ready(function() {
            $("#search_form").on("submit", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.post("result.php?query=" + encodeURIComponent($("#list_search").val()), function (data) {
                    var res = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (res.divs) {
                         $('#search_result').html("");
                        for (var i = 0; i < res.divs.length; i++) {
                            $('#search_result').append(res.divs[i]);
                       }
                    } else {
                        $('#search_result').html("No matched coupons found !");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What's the problem my friend?

Comment: if you need result on another page than why you need ajax? just do submit and according to your post data do select query and display result.

Comment: Can you clarify? You want to search on index.php, then display on coupons.php? Then you don't need AJAX. 
Or, you want the same functionality on the coupons.php page? Just include the same javascript. 
As Roy asked, what is your actual problem?

Comment: @delboy1978uk Yes i am searching some keywords on index.php and then when i click the button it shoul display result at coupon.php `div` with id `search_result`

Comment: ah, so you wish to load another file into a div? You would use .load() in jQuery for that I think.

`$('#search_result').load('coupon.php');`

Alternatiely you might need to do a $.post() and send whatever vars to the page, then do `$('#search_result').html(data);` where data is the html returned by the ajax call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you need to somehow show result on another page but cannot use server side. I don't know why you want to do that, but ajax is surely not the option and if you can't use server side, you can do this. Instead of sending the JSON response on your coupons.php page. Send the search query to the coupons page. So you should create a search form in index.php something like this

```
<form action="coupons.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="query" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then in your coupons.php page you can access your search query by **window.location.search** This will give you the query user search on

Now using this query, here on coupons.php page you will write your logic to get the json response and print the result in **#search_result** element.

So your coupons.php will look something like

```
$("document").ready(function() {
            var q = window.location.search; // q is your query string you got from index.php

                $.post('result.php'+q, function (data) { 
                    var res = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (res.divs) {
                         $('#search_result').html("");
                        for (var i = 0; i < res.divs.length; i++) {
                            $('#search_result').append(res.divs[i]);
                       }
                    } else {
                        $('#search_result').html("No matched coupons found !");
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Just tried your code and debugged it. it gives `q = "?query=gucci"` on line `var q = window.location.search; `. Why is it so?

Comment: ok ! i have solved it. Thankyou so much for this. :) I just changed line `$.post('result.php?query='+q,` to  `$.post("result.php"+q,` . And it worked..